# Content Available missing in moon-apns payload

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, moonapns

I need to send a payload using moon-apns.
currently i can see that the payload structure of *NotificationPayload* is like below-

```
  public class NotificationPayload
    {
        public NotificationPayload(string deviceToken);
        public NotificationPayload(string deviceToken, string alert);
        public NotificationPayload(string deviceToken, string alert, int badge);
        public NotificationPayload(string deviceToken, string alert, int badge, string sound);

        public NotificationAlert Alert { get; set; }
        public int? Badge { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, object[]> CustomItems { get; }
        public string DeviceToken { get; set; }
        public string Sound { get; set; }

        public void AddCustom(string key, params object[] values);
        public string ToJson();
        public override string ToString();
    }
```

Where is Content-Available? it must be the part of aps.. Is it missing or not available in moon-apns? if so how to send Content-Available as a part of aps as showed in below example-

```
{"aps":{"alert":"Helo","badge":1,"content-available" : 1,"sound":"default"}}
```

I tried Add custom ; but it adds custom property outside the aps string.

Answer (score 1):

I have used below method in Node.js. It's working to me.

agent.createMessage().device(device).contentAvailable('1').alert("loc-key","Title": "Message").send();